# How to convert 3 letter language code to corresponding text?

Tags: java

Do we have any java libraries to convert 3 letter language code to its corresponding language with localization support?

Like, 
ENG -> English

PS: I guess its a bad question. But, google was of not a good help. Hence, turning to you all. Probably, my search term was not accurate.

Comment: You mean to say something like country code to country name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Locale`'s `getDisplayLanguage()` method:

```
Locale eng = Locale.forLanguageTag("ENG");    // Make a locale from language code
System.out.println(eng.getDisplayLanguage()); // Obtain language display name
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/1uiUEG)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about a Java library but this might help.

https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php

It has the data you are looking for.  You might have to scrape it off the page and put it into your Java code.